# Trouble with session attributes getting replicated in Tomcat 6

Tags: session, tomcat, session-replication

I have configured Tomcat 6 with in-memory session replication.  I am also using IIS 7 (I know, I know) and the AJP connector via isapi_redirector.  The cluster is working properly and I am able to replicate session attributes using the SessionExample in the examples war.  The problem is that I am unable to do the same in my custom application.  I have added the distributable tag to the web.xml file on both servers in my test cluster.  However, I don't see any message in the logs mentioning the attributes getting sent to the cluster (I see them for SessionExample).  The only primary differences that I can see in my app from the examples:

1. The examples war uses servlet 2.5.  I am still required to use 2.4.
2. My application uses SSO and requires the user to login.
3. The application is a portal application.

Also, in the code of the application, I am setting a simple string in the attribute, so nothing fancy.

So, I was wondering if anyone has some tips to get this working?

Thanks

Here is the cluster section within  of my server.xml:

```
<Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster" 
    channelSendOptions="6">
    <Manager className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager" 
            expireSessionsOnShutdown="false" 
            notifyListenersOnReplication="true"/>
    <Channel className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.GroupChannel">
        <Membership className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastService" 
            address="228.0.0.104" 
            port="45564" 
            frequency="500" 
            dropTime="10000"/>
        <Receiver className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.NioReceiver" 
            address="auto" 
            port="4000" 
            autoBind="100" 
            selectorTimeout="7000" 
            maxThreads="6"
            timeout="15000"/>
        <Sender className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.ReplicationTransmitter">
            <Transport className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.PooledParallelSender"
                timeout="70000"/>
        </Sender>
        <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.TcpFailureDetector"/>
        <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.MessageDispatch15Interceptor"/>
    </Channel>
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve" 
        filter=".*\.gif;.*\.js;.*\.jpg;.*\.png;.*\.htm;.*\.html;.*\.css;.*\.txt;"/>
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteBinderValve"/>
    <Deployer className="org.apache.catalina.ha.deploy.FarmWarDeployer" 
        tempDir="/apache-tomcat-6.0.37/war-deploy/war-temp/" 
        deployDir="/apache-tomcat-6.0.37/webapps/" 
        watchDir="/apache-tomcat-6.0.37/war-deploy/war-listen/" 
        watchEnabled="true"/>
    <ClusterListener className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteSessionIDBinderListener"/>
    <ClusterListener className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.ClusterSessionListener"/>
</Cluster>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry.  I found the issue.  I was expecting to see messages in the log regarding the creation of the session attributes.  I didn't realize that the examples project had a session listener that was outputting the messages to the log.  I was thinking that it was simply from the log level that I had set.

Thanks to anyone who read this post.